# multiple upload loop only once

Tags: php, html, pdo

i have multiple file upload but it only loop once and stop
its mean that i get in data base only one file

i have tried to insert the db part inside the loop but its multiple rows in db
and i dont want it like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $websites = $_POST['websites'];
    foreach($_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['documents']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['documents']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['documents']['type'][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".time().$file_name);
    }
    print_r($file_name);
    $pdo = DB();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO client_form_7 
                            (client_id, documents, websites) 
                     VALUES (:client_id, :documents, :websites)");
    $stmt->bindParam("client_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam("documents", $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam("websites", $websites, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

i want all my files stored in db as array

**EDIT**

**my solution**

just create empty array before the foreach and inside the foreach push the file name to the new array and outside encoded the array full of the file names with `json_encode` and insert it to the db thank you guys for the workthrou‬‏

**code**

```
$arr = array();
  foreach($_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
  $file_name = $key.$_FILES['documents']['name'][$key];
  $file_size =$_FILES['documents']['size'][$key];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'][$key];
  $file_type=$_FILES['documents']['type'][$key];
  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".time().$file_name);
  $arr[] = $file_name;
}
 $files = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: So you don't want one row, and you don't want multiple rows? Confused.

Comment: So you had better describe the resulting SINGLE ROW in the table that you want to build from multiple file uploads

Comment: _One small point_ errrr no ___One Big Point___ Currently you are storing the file to disk with a **DIFFERENT** name than the one you are storing onto the database.  As fagin once said --- _I think I'd better think it out again_

Comment: If you want to put those files into different columns in one row, then this makes rather little sense for an “unlimited” amount of files to begin with (because number of columns simply isn’t “dynamic”.) In that case, I’d rather expect to see a for loop run over a defined interval.

Comment: @jon stirling i want it in one row in my solution to this its do it but only loop once and only one file inserted to database

Comment: @YosefDadya So like Riggs asked, what is that row supposed to look like with multiple files?

Comment: @jonstirling an array that's hold the names of the files

Comment: MySQL doesn't really have arrays.

Comment: @jonstirling Yes i now but there is a way to store this like multiple select and option with json_encode()?(i have tried this with json_encode and it's dosen't work)

Comment: You can store them multiple ways, you could store the JSON, you could store them as a CSV list, you could add a new table that links to client_form_7. Many options. That's why we're asking what _you_ want. If you want it to be JSON, update the code in the question to reflect what you tried with using `json_encode` with an explanation of what exactly didn't work, and we'll have a look

Comment: **my solution**